# Usar vários nomes com funções distintas em uma variável

Tags: javascript, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação, declaração-de-variável

Veja estas declaracões de variáveis:

```
var level = 0;
var atual_sequence = 0;
```

Eu poderia junta-las assim?:

```
var level, atual_sequence = 0;
```

Uma afetaria na funcionalidade da outra?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: No caso são suas variaveis diferentes, indepentende de usar `var x, y;` ou `var x; var y;`, portanto uma não influencia na outra.

Comment: Como assim? `1` e `-24` são nomes inválidos para variáveis em JS.

Comment: O código já não fazia muito sentido, agora ele sequer é válido. Procure dizer exatamente onde quer chegar e dar exemplos reais.

Comment: @Elaine mostre um exemplo **funcional** do problema para entendermos o que você fez.

Comment: A pergunta está bem difícil de entender, porém parece haver uma falha de entendimento sobre declaração de múltiplas variáveis de uma vez. Quando você usa: `var x, y = 10;`, somente `y` tem valor 10, o valor de `x` é `undefined`. Pra complicar, em todos os seus exemplos (incluindo os que você removeu na edição) os valores parecem estar do lado errado da atribuição. O formato correto é `var variavel = valor`, e não var `valor = variavel`. Pode esclarecer por favor?

Comment: foi um exemplo completamente ficticio, @GuilhermeNascimento entao elas sao autonomas entao mas com valores iguais, junta-las seria o mesmo que definilas separadamente?

Comment: Sim a `,` em variaveis não junta as duas, é apenas um modo mais simples de criar as variáveis no tempo de execução, como eu disse `var x, y;` e `var x; var y;` são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Boa noite Elaine, resta alguma duvida? As respostas fornecidas não lhe ajudaram, por favor informe se falta algo, se não, por favor marque a resposta que mais lhe agradar como correta (se a resposta resolveu a sua duvida). Grato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira pergunta que você deve fazer é: que vantagem tem em aproveitar um nome de variável para fazer duas coisas diferentes?

Em geral a resposta é nenhuma ou então é apenas para digitar uns caracteres a menos, que seria uma vantagem bem questionável. Então é sempre melhor dar mais legibilidade, deixar claro qual é a intenção de cada variável. Não só usar nomes separados para cada coisa, é dar nomes significativos do que está guardando nela.

Se a dúvida é declarar as variáveis (no plurar) na mesma linha ou não, depende muito do caso, costuma ser uma questão de estilo mas em geral o melhor é ter cada declaração em cada linha:

```
var var1 = 0;
var var2 = 1;
```

não é tão melhor assim que

```
var var1 = 0, var2 = 1;
```

mas em nomes mais longos, em listas maiores, pode se tornar menos legível.

Também dá para fazer isto:

```
var var1 = 0,
    var2 = 1;
```

Mas não há muito ganho. E pode haver desvantagens se precisar mudar a lista de variáveis depois já que cria uma exceção na linearidade da sintaxe.

Deve-se tomar cuidado especialmente quando ambas tiverem o mesmo valor. Há uma tentação de fazer isto:

```
var var1 = var2 = 0;
```

Isto provavelmente não faz o que se espera. A variável `var1` terá escopo local e valerá 0. Já a variável `var2` também valerá 0 mas seu escopo será global e não local, como muitos podem supor.

Também deve tomar cuidado se fizer

```
var var1, var2 = 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/VarDeclaration.js).

Somente `var2` terá o valor 0, `var1` não terá valor definido.

Então afetaria a funcionalidade e mesmo que seja o que se deseja, o que é pouco provável, não é recomendado porque não dá clara indicação da intenção.

[Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Answer (score 2):

*Não*, a virgula (`,`) não junta as variáveis, isto é apenas um modo de definir elas sem escrever tanto, usar `var x, y;` e `var x; var y;` são a mesma coisa.

Por exemplo:

```
var x = 1, y =2;
console.log(x, y);//Vai mostrar duas variáveis do tipo `integer` assim: "1, 2"
```

A situação com quebra de linha:

```
var x = 1,
    y =2;

console.log(x, y);//Vai mostrar duas variáveis do tipo `int` assim: "1, 2"
```

A situação isolada, ou seja cada variável com seu próprio `var`:

```
var x = 1;
var y =2;

console.log(x, y);//Vai imprimir isto "1, 2"
```

Em todos os casos teremos o mesmo resultado, se você quer juntas duas variaveis em uma string, você terá que fazer algo como:

```
var x = 1, y =2;

var z = '' + x + '' + y;
console.log(z);//Vai mostrar uma variável do tipo `string` assim: "12"
```

Você também pode usar um `array` para ter todos dados em um "local" (vai depender da sua necessidade) e após isto usar o `join`:

```
var x = [1, 2];

console.log(x.join(""));//Vai imprimir isto "12"
```